# Use a keyboard shortcut to trigger a html-supported window based on the selected text

Tags: ide, monaco-editor

I would like to add a feature in my editor: users select a text, and click on a keyboard shortcut (e.g., `F9`), then a window with content by html (eg, [a table like this](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/2856#issuecomment-1001282986)) appears next to the selection, in the end, users move the mouse or press a keyboard shortcut to make the window disappear.

I understand that we could use `addDynamicKeybinding` or [like here](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#interacting-with-the-editor-adding-an-action-to-an-editor-instance) to add a keyboard shortcut.

But for the window, it seems that we have only diagnostic window that support html, right? If so, the only use case I know about diagnostic window is by `HoverProvider` [like here](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-hover-provider-example), where we need to hover on a text to make the diagnostic window appear.

Does anyone know how to use a keyboard shortcut to trigger a html-supported window, whose content is related to the selected text?